# Scale dependency for labels in KML files with many placemarks

Tags: kml, google-earth, editing, arcgis

There is a KML file that I created by exporting a layer from ArcGIS10.0. The file shows some placemarks that I need to be labeled. However, I want the labels (and the points themselves) to be visible in Google Earth only at or below a certain altitude. I know that using the `<Region>` tag is the way to do this, but, with a triple-digit number of placemarks, typing in the tag and all the rest of the code for every single placemark does not seem very practical.

The points are all located in one folder, and I wonder if I can use `<Region>` at the folder level. However, placing `<Region>` and the rest of the code after the `<folder>` tag and `</Region>` just before `</folder>` did not work. If I am to modify the behavior of the labels at the folder level, where should I place the tags?
Also, how do I edit KML code? I know that I can right-click a file in Google Earth, copy it, and paste the code into a text editor, but how do I get the edited code back into the file?

Sorry for such trivial questions, I'm as new to KML as can be.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, you've tried this:

```
<folder>
  <region>
    <placemark></placemark>
    <placemark></placemark>
    <placemark></placemark>
    ...
  </region>
</folder>
```

From the KML [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions):

> Also, within the KML file, notice that the Region is a sibling of the
>   image (or geometry) whose visibility it affects.

Therefore what you want to do is this:

```
<folder>
  <region>
    [scale limits go here]
  </region>

  <placemark></placemark>
  <placemark></placemark>
  <placemark></placemark>
    ...
</folder>
```

In terms of editing the KML file - just open it directly in your text editor, don't copy it out of Google Earth.

Comment: I'll try. What text editor should I use, though? I get gibberish when I open the file with Notepad or Notepad++, and Word refuses to open the file at all. Also, after the `<folder>` tag, does the `<Region>` tag go before or after the `<name>` tag?

Comment: Is it a KML or KMZ file? If it's a KMZ, that's basically a zip file with a KML file inside it - rename it to .zip or open it with your favourite zip file program.

Comment: re. tags - try not to think of it as "after the `<folder>` tag and before the `<name>` tag" - XML files are a heirarchy, so if your `<region>` and `<name>` tags are both within the `<folder></folder>` pair then it doesn't (shouldn't) matter which order they are in. This is what the documentation I quoted above means about siblings - `<region>`, `<name>` and your `<placemark>` tags are all siblings, and children of the `<folder>`.